Performance bottleneck in multihreaded process
I'm making a program that parses a graph from an .mtx file. I'm using a thread to read from the file, every line of the file contains two vertexes (representing an edge). The thread inserts the edge in a Producer Consumer circular buffer (not inserting edges that are knots). For every vertex I initialize an ordered linked list, where a thread will try to insert the new end of the edge. If the edge is already present in the list, it does not insert it.
Accesses to each list is serialized using a method that uses a bitmap to see if the corresponding list is occupied by another thread.
I noticed a big bottleneck in performance: almost 25 minutes to parse a roughly 200Mb file.
I used a profiler to see what I was missing and I found 2 things:

The insertion in the list kills performance even though the list is kept ordered

Let's say the edges are ordered in the .mtx file (not quite, but I have big clusters of edges that will end in the same list close to eachother in the file). So since I'm inserting them in the buffer in the order I read them, most of the time, the calling thread will be blocked when trying to access the list.


I'm trying to think a way to work around this the things I thought are:

Use an hash table to exclude all the duplicate edges: but since I have in the order of 10^6 edges, allocating the hash table alone takes 350Mb.

Randomize the extraction from the buffer: [I dont know if I can actually do it] but this would prevent the clusters hence threads will be blocked less, hopefully.

Using a self balancing tree structure so I can beneficiate of the logarithmic time insertion and search. Even though I will not be able to access edges in ranges. I could solve that using a B+ tree but that seems way overkill for the project.

Use an array and ordering that from time to time (Seems stupid to think about this)


Other than this I'm stuck. I would appreciate if anyone would help me out.
Thanks in advance

Is 350Mb a lot on your platform? On a PC I wouldn't even worry about that.

"...Using a self balancing tree structure...Even tho I will not be able to access edges in ranges." If you need an ordered list after you have read the whole file, you can generate it by walking the tree that you built while you were reading the file.

What are the vertices exactly? 2D coordinates? What are "knot edges"? You keep a linked list for every vertex, yes? And then you insert the "new end" of an edge in this list? Does that mean the other end of an edge, where the first end is the vertex that initialized the list? So in the end, you will have a linked list for every vertex and each linked list contains two vertices that belong to the same edge? What does ordered list exactly mean? What are all these other threads that are also accessing these lists? How fast is your parser thread when isolated?

@Marcel: the vertices are just positive integers, knot edges refer to an edge that connect a vertex to itself. In an edge (x,y) x identifies the list, and y is a node in the list. In the end I expect to have a linked list for each vertex (for example in list x i will have all vertices (positive integers) that are connected directly to x). Ordered list means that each node of the list keeps a value that is bigger than the previos node. Every thread extract an edge from the buffer, and tries to insert it in the corresponding list. The parser when isolated is not a problem at all.

It is clearer now, but I still don't think I understand the whole picture. So you are trying to read in the graph from a file. Why is there not just one thread that goes through the file line by line and records an edge in an adjacency matrix by setting matrix[i][j] to 1? There wouldn't even be a need to filter duplicates, because then you just set the same matrix[i][j] to 1 over and over again. What is the purpose of the circular buffer?

How dense is your graph? For a very dense graph, an adjacency matrix is the most efficient way. For a low density graph, an adjacency list would be better, but that doesn't imply that it's a linked list. You could use an array, just append new edges and only after reading, sort and discard duplicates. Concerning the multithreading, lots of things (e.g. pipeline pingpong and thread convoys) could go wrong, it would require a look at the code. BTW: Consider codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

@UlrichEckhardt I actually didn't think about the array thing, i guess I was just fixating about solving the problem that I didn't even ponder considering if what I did was effective. I will make more tests, thanks a lot

BTW: I meant "cacheline pingpong" (aka "false sharing"), not "pipeline pingpong".
